# Creating new datarow on a SQL Server with automized date from DBMS doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, getdate

Hi I'm trying to create a new datarow on my SQL Server.
It works pretty well if I transmit the MAT_DBDATE Column manually with my c# code.

Heres an example:

C# Code:

```
private void ButtonMaterialAnlegen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataRow dr = DSMaterial.TBL_MATERIAL.NewRow();

            dr["MAT_FK_LFR_ID"] = ComboBoxLieferant.SelectedValue;
            dr["MAT_FK_LAG_ID"] = ComboBoxLagerort.SelectedValue;
            dr["MAT_NAME"] = TextBoxBeschreibung.Text;
            dr["MAT_DBDATE"] = DateTime.Now;

            DSMaterial.TBL_MATERIAL.Rows.Add(dr);

            TAMaterial.Update(DSMaterial);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But if I want the SQL Server to add the date automatically via the getdate() command as default it doesn't work. I only got an NoNullAllowedException.

The MAT_DBDATE Colum has the following specifications:

```
    [MAT_DBDATE] DATETIME2 (7) CONSTRAINT [DF_TBL_MATERIAL_MAT_DBDATE] DEFAULT (sysdatetime()) NOT NULL,
```

Thank's for help!